# No "Copy content from" wagtail-modeltranslation button

Tags: python, django, internationalization, wagtail, django-modeltranslation

The "COPY CONTENT FROM [available translation languages]" button is not showing in the admin page editing interface.
The package was installed properly, following official documentation.
What can cause the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in app register order. wagtail_modeltranslation app should be registered on top of user apps